# for in a parameter function python - zip dynamic

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I have dynamic `zip()` function call:

```
zip(id, value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4])
```

Value has a dynamic length: it could contain 3 or 4 or 7 elements, etc.
Is there a way I can make the `zip()` function dynamic and work with a variable number of elements from `value`?

e.g. **pseudo code**:

```
zip(id, for i in range(0,len(value)): value[i])
```

Comment: @khelwood: they are trying to pass in a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `*args` *call* syntax:

```
zip(id, *value)
```

Prepending `value` with `*` tells Python to apply each entry in `value` as a separate argument to `zip()`.